# ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a Multicolumn expression index, but when I create the index, the following message is output:

```
--detail message 
wapgrowth=> create index CONCURRENTLY idx_test on  tmp_table using btree (skyid, to_char(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), actiontype );
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE


--table ddl
wapgrowth=> \d tmp_table
               Table "wapgrowth.tmp_table"
   Column    |            Type             |   Modifiers   
-------------+-----------------------------+---------------
 id          | integer                     | not null
 actiontype  | character varying(20)       | 
 apptype     | character varying(20)       | 
 score       | integer                     | 
 create_time | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 skyid       | integer                     | 
Indexes:
```

Comment: If you are facing this with char fields, just put the char field name in quotations, like "field"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to this thread in the hackers mailing list:

http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg86725.html

this is intended behaviour as `to_char` depends on the LC_MESSAGES setting

In your case this apparently doesn't make sense as the format you are using will never depend on the locale, so if you do need to use the text representation in the index, you can create your own to_char() function and mark it as immutable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_char(some_time timestamp) 
  RETURNS text
AS
$BODY$
    select to_char($1, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

If you have to use it as a text in the index (and cannot use the cast to a date as Sam suggested) you will need to create your own formatting function that you can mark as immutable. That can then be used in the index.

But to make Postgres *use* the index you will need to call `my_to_char()` in your SQL statements as well. It will not recognize it when you use the built-in `to_char()`

But I do think Sam's suggestion using a straight date in the index is probably better

Comment: Thanks for your advise, After alter the function "to_char" to "IMMUTABLE" ,it woks now , but is there any risk after doing this?

Comment: skytf=# alter function to_char(timestamp with time zone, text) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION

Answer (score 29):

This explains more in detail:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKFQuwbcMfesmNkm19mXFLXP14sP5BiPsR1GSkY1suKiM1rukg%40mail.gmail.com

basically the timezone depends on the server, and thus the result might change if somebody changes it. But if you lock the timezone:

`date(timezone('UTC', create_time))`

it will work.

Comment: best answer, because it works whatever the timestamp is set

Comment: That's great, wrapping my date/time column - `timezone('UTC', date_time_column)` - was all I needed to do (i.e. no need to declare an immutable function). Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me. Can you tell me what I did wrong? create unique index my_date_idx 
   on mydb.mytable (
    (case rst_id when 1 then to_char(timezone('GMT', my_date),'yyyymmddhh24missff6') end)
   );

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I have a `date` column to work with but `timezone()` works with it. Dunno. I wanted to get rid of my custom, immutable function but so far no luck.

Comment: @SME that is probably because the to_char see the answer of a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 4):

`to_char` of a timestamp-without-timezone is not an immutable function, because the conversion depends on your local time-zone setting. That means the index wouldn't be portable to another computer in a different time zone, and Postgres won't allow it. I think the problem will go away if you declare create_time as a time with timezone.

Comment: I have tried to create a expression index on a timestamp column with timezone, but it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using to_char to format your timestamp as YYYY-MM-DD, try casting your timestamp to a date type, which will have the same effect:

```
create index CONCURRENTLY idx_test on  tmp_table using btree (skyid, cast(create_time as date), actiontype );
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I tried the way, but it didn't work neither.

Comment: What version of postgres are you using? It worked for me using version 9.0.3.

Comment: skytf=> create index CONCURRENTLY idx_test on  test_39 using btree (skyid, cast(create_time as date ));
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Comment: I don't have an explanation for why casting your timestamp to a date doesn't work for you, but try the `date_trunc()` function instead. It is is IMMUTABLE (for timestamp without  time zone). `create index CONCURRENTLY idx_test2 on  tmp_table using btree (skyid, date_trunc('day', create_time), actiontype );`

Comment: skytf=# alter function to_char(timestamp with time zone, text) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day it looks like you're trying to index a "YYYY-MM-DD" representation of create_time. Why not just INDEX create_time? The problem is to_char() is MUTABLE because the locale environment variable could change, which changes the output of to_char().

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/charset.html

If you have control over the schema, you could add a new column (e.g. create_date TEXT) and INDEX that, then setup a trigger that handles the inserts. In fact, if you created a way of converting your TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE to TEXT, you could INDEX that in a constant way. a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion was a good one since I don't think you care about locale.

The problem you're running in to is all DATE and TIME handling code obeys locale, which isn't IMMUTABLE, therefore you can't easily INDEX functions that rely on those data types.

Answer (score 0):

for the timestamptz field, it looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON your_table(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM your_column_timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'));
```