# How to optimize sql query? Seems distinct is very slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I am not a db speccialist, so question =)

How to optimize such:

```
select count(DISTINCT userid) 
from users 
where date_trunc('month',login_date)=date_trunc('month','2012-01-12'::date)
```

Table rows count is less then 1.5 million. I have an index on login_date, although query execution time is same as without it. Also field userid is primary key.

On server machine this query takes some more than 2000 ms. The first guy who can help bring out the best performance will get reputation++ :D

----------------a'b'c'd'e'f'g'h' SOLUTION----------------------------------

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_date_trunc_month(some_date DATE) 
  RETURNS DATE 
AS $$
BEGIN
   return date_trunc('month',$1);
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;


CREATE INDEX computedIdx ON gameuser_daily_activity (my_date_trunc_month(login_date));

select count(DISTINCT gameuser_fk) from gameuser_daily_activity where my_date_trunc_month(login_date)=my_date_trunc_month('2012-01-12'::date)
```

AND it takes 110 ms  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define this index:

`CREATE INDEX computedIdx ON users (date_trunc('month',login_date))`

Comment: Hm,ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973030/error-functions-in-index-expression-must-be-marked-immutable - create a function marked immutable to convert the date.

Comment: Thank you. Optimized to 110 ms! Will wait if solution without custom function exists =)

Comment: or say `date_trunc('month',login_date::timestamp)`

Answer (score 3):

IF UserID is primary Key it will be distinct you dont need to put distinct in it..
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

and preffered clustered indexed on primary key

Comment: Sorry please, the PK is on both fields (userid, login_date)

Comment: Ok so its a composite primary key..
where date_trunc('month',login_date)='01'
could improve the performance little and UserID should have been the primary key it will help you in many other cases too

Comment: Actually table name is user_daily_activity. I renamed it to users, now I see I shouldn't do that. Composite key is necessary

Comment: Ohkk Then the Best thing you can do is create a Clustered Index on UserID

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this?

```
select count(DISTINCT userid) 
from users 
where 
login_date >= '2012-01-12'::date and 
login_date < '2012-01-12'::date + '1month'::interval
```

removing expressions around your indexed columns will make the optimizer job easier.

Comment: Of course you will need an index on login_date for this to be effective.

Comment: I am not an Postgresql expert, you will have to work on the date ranges. The thing is: don't put expressions around your indexed column so the optimizer has a clear hint that you want to use that index.