# PostgreSQL: Scan relevant partitions only

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to analyze why a certain query takes quite a long time. It runs on a partitioned PostgreSQL (v9.1) table. It is partitioned monthly. The rule is based on the a column which holds an integer representation of the date (so in example 20130801).

If I write a query like this one:

```
EXPLAIN     SELECT DISTINCT (user_id)
FROM users
WHERE
    date_tk >= 20130801
```

Only the relevant partitions get selected. But, when I run something like this, it scans all the partitions:

```
EXPLAIN     SELECT DISTINCT (user_id)
FROM users 
WHERE
    date_tk >= TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - '30 days'::INTERVAL, 'yyyyMMdd')::INT
```

Now I casted the constraint date to int, so it seems to be ok I would assume, but unfortunately it isn't. Does somebody have an idea on how to improve this query so that only the relevant partitions get scanned?

Thanks,
Diddy

Comment: here is some explanations and solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973030/error-functions-in-index-expression-must-be-marked-immutable

Comment: Thanks a lot! This explained it: "At the end of the day it looks like you're trying to index a "YYYY-MM-DD" representation of create_time. Why not just INDEX create_time? The problem is to_char() is MUTABLE because the locale environment variable could change, which changes the output of to_char()."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you're using isn't considered immutable by Postgres (for the same reason now() isn't), so Postgres won't use it to consider when optimizing the lookup. Toss in an extra where clause that is constant and far enough in the past.

Alternatively, wouldn't using time stamps directly when partitioning avoid the issue altogether?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can supply constants as parameters to the query at runtime, so at least I have a workaround.