# How to create composite index in Postgres 9

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I tried

```
create temp table test (kuupaev date, kellaaeg char(5)  ) on commit drop;
create index on test ((kuupaev||kellaaeg));
```

but got error

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

How to this index in Postgres 9 ?

In Postgres 8 it worked.

**Update**

Commands

```
create temp table test (kuupaev date, kellaaeg char(5)  ) on commit drop;
create index test on test ((kuupaev||kellaaeg));
```

in

```
"PostgreSQL 9.3.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit"
```

cause error

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

but in

```
"PostgreSQL 8.4.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1400, 32-bit"
```

they work OK

Comment: What's wrong with `create index on test (kuupaev, kellaaeg);`

Comment: I need to speed up query like `SELECT 
    max( kuupaev||kellaaeg ) as res
  from test
  where kuupaev <=date'20140101' and 
     kuupaev||kellaaeg <= '2014010114 23'
` Will your index speed it ?

Comment: Why not use the columns individually in the `where` clause? `where kuupaev <= date '2014-01-01' and keellag < '23'`. This concatenation doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Application using such select is deployed to product sites and its upgrading is difficult. Your where clause produces different result, for example will newer return with kellaaeg='24' values. Is correct replacement  (kuupaev,kellaaev)<(date'20140101','14 23') ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the `14` as part  of the `keelaav` column. `where kuupaev <= date '2014-01-01' and keellag <= '14 23'` should be equivalent. The comparison `<= '14 23'` seems strange - but that was the same with your initial query. I'm tempted to say that there is something wrong with your data model.

Comment: This is a similar question that explains the background for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5973030/330315

Comment: There's not really such a thing as "postgres 9" or "postgres 8". PostgreSQL's quirky versioning means that "9.2", "9.3", etc are all very different. It's a bit like saying "Windows 6"... do you mean Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8? They all have the internal version number "6".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My comment point was that query in my question is basically as `(a,b)<=(v1,v2)`. In your comment you recommend to replace it with `a<=v1 and b<=v2` This produces different result than query in question.

Comment: @Andrus Yes, it does; the equivalent of the composite comparison `(a,b) <= (v1, v2)` would be `(a < v1) or (a = v1 and b <= v2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying `pg_operator` shows that the relevant operator implementation function is `anytextcat`.

```
regress=> select l.typname, r.typname, o.oprcode 
          from pg_operator o 
            inner join pg_type l on (o.oprleft = l.oid) 
            inner join pg_type r on (o.oprright = r.oid) 
          where oprname = '||';

   typname   |   typname   |     oprcode     
-------------+-------------+-----------------
 anyarray    | anyelement  | array_append
 anyelement  | anyarray    | array_prepend
 anyarray    | anyarray    | array_cat
 text        | text        | textcat
 varbit      | varbit      | bitcat
 bytea       | bytea       | byteacat
 text        | anynonarray | textanycat
 anynonarray | text        | anytextcat
 tsvector    | tsvector    | tsvector_concat
 tsquery     | tsquery     | tsquery_or
(10 rows)
```

`\df+ anytextcat` shows that it's `stable` (I'm running 9.4beta2+git changes, but it's the same back to 9.2).

Looking up the relevant line of `pg_proc.h` and `git blame`ing it, the last commit was cd30728f, but looking at `git show` demonstrates that it isn't relevant. So I skip it with `git blame cd30728f^ -- ./src/include/catalog/pg_proc.h`. Working backwards I see that the changes were:

```
cd30728f - Allow LEAKPROOF functions for better performance of security views. (9.2)
3db6524f - Mark some more I/O-conversion-invoking functions as stable not volatile. (9.2)
8f9fe6ed - Add notion of a "transform function" that can simplify function calls. (9.2)
c82d931d - Fix the volatility marking of textanycat() and anytextcat() (9.0)
```

Of those, only c82d931d is really relevant. 3db6524f changes it from volatile to stable, but that doesn't help you.

`git show c82d931d` describes the commit that likely caused this behaviour change as:

```
commit c82d931dd180965a9a0c06acc764404f91de8170
Author: Tom Lane <tgl@sss.pgh.pa.us>
Date:   Thu May 27 16:20:11 2010 +0000

    Fix the volatility marking of textanycat() and anytextcat(): they were marked
    immutable, but that is wrong in general because the cast from the polymorphic
    argument to text could be stable or even volatile.  Mark them volatile for
    safety.  In the typical case where the cast isn't volatile, the planner will
    deduce the correct expression volatility after inlining the function, so
    performance is not lost.  The just-committed fix in CREATE INDEX also ensures
    this won't break any indexing cases that ought to be allowed.

    Per discussion, I'm not bumping catversion for this change, as it doesn't
    seem critical enough to force an initdb on beta testers.
```

According to:

```
git branch --contains c82d931d
```

it was introduced in the PostgreSQL 9.0.0 release.

The commit message suggests that it's *supposed* not to cause any issues with indexes that're safe, and the later change shouldn't make any difference there.

However, looking closer, you're not using `text` or `varchar`. You're using the horrible old `char` type, which is internally `bpchar` in PostgreSQL.

The issue here will be either that there's a subtle behaviour with `char` that's locale dependent, or that an oversight caused this change not to handle the case for `char`. I'd need to dig much deeper into the sources than I have time for tonight to be able to be sure, and frankly for the `char(n)` type I don't really care to.

You should probably just use `varchar(5)`. If you need space padding, consider doing it with `lpad`.

Otherwise, please report this issue to pgsql-bugs - but make sure you show the **exact** versions, from `SELECT version()`.

Comment: I cannot change to varchar. This is big application and such change requires large amount of code rewrite. I updated question and added versions. How to report a bug ?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/support/submitbug/ ... but **read those instructions properly first** or the report won't be taken seriously. You should include a link to this question in the report, but make sure the report its self includes all required information directly, don't just say "look at this link please".  Use the words "regression" and "backward compatibility break", it might get more attention. Note that reporting a bug doesn't mean anything will happen, especially for somewhat obscure stuff like this; that's what http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ is for.

Comment: Recently I have reported pg_dump bug in psql-general mailing list where I'm member simply by writing to it. Tom was reading this and made commit. Report is in this question update. Is this OK?

Comment: @Andrus I didn't understand what you said, so I really don't know. I'm off to bed now anyway (it's late here in Australia). Remember to include a link to this post though, otherwise people will waste time duplicating the same research and be very grumpy.

Comment: I posted related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165745/how-find-greatest-tuple-before-given-2-column-tuple-in-postgres-fast