# How find greatest tuple before given 2-column tuple in postgres fast

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

How to increase select statement speed in Postgres 9.0 ?

Table has required index present. Desired result can obtained using index (kuupaev,kellaaeg) immediately.
However Postgres scans all rows:

```
explain analyze SELECT 
    max( kuupaev||kellaaeg ) as res
  from firma2.ALGSA 
  where laonr=1 and kuupaev <=current_date and 
     (kuupaev,kellaaeg) <= ( current_date, '23 59'  )

"Aggregate  (cost=6932.65..6932.67 rows=1 width=10) (actual time=1608.590..1608.592 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on algsa  (cost=0.00..6571.49 rows=144464 width=10) (actual time=0.032..922.431 rows=144458 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((laonr = 1::numeric) AND (kuupaev <= ('now'::text)::date) AND (ROW(kuupaev, kellaaeg) <= ROW(('now'::text)::date, '23 59'::bpchar)))"
"Total runtime: 1608.846 ms"
```

In real query instead of 1, current_date and '23 59' there are variable parameters.

Table has both indexes present but postgres will not use them. 
Indexes can changed and query can re-written if this helps. 
Table structure cannot changed. char columns cannot replaced with varchar columns. kuupaev must be date and kellaaeg must be char(5) type.

Query contains reduntant condition `kuupaev <=current_date` but index is still not used.

I tried also `SELECT max( (kuupaev,kellaaeg ))` but got error that max() function does not exist.

```
CREATE TABLE firma2.algsa
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  laonr numeric(2,0),
  kuupaev date NOT NULL,
  kellaaeg character(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
  osak character(10) NOT NULL,
  toode character(20) NOT NULL,
  partii character(15),
  kogus numeric(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  hind numeric(15,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  kulum numeric(15,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  tegkogus numeric(12,4),
  stkuupaev date,
  klient character(12),
  masin character(5),
  CONSTRAINT algsa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE INDEX algsa_kuupaev_idx
  ON firma2.algsa
  USING btree
  (kuupaev);

CREATE INDEX algsa_kuupaev_kellaaeg_idx
  ON firma2.algsa
  USING btree
  (kuupaev, kellaaeg);
```

using

"PostgreSQL 9.0.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit"

Comment: Please tell me how many records are in your table `ALGSA` ?

Comment: You can see this in explain analyze output from question: estimated was `rows=144464` and real was `rows=144458`. In other sites table may be bigger.

Comment: 9.0.3? Really? Update to the current point release. It's a simple database restart. The current 9.0 release is 9.0.18, you're missing 15 patch levels...

Comment: Why are you storing a time in a `char`? `kellaaeg` should at least be a `time` column. Even better: merge `kuupaev` and `kellaaeg` into a single column of type `timestamp`. You should really listen to [Tom's advice from the mailing list](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/How-to-find-greatest-record-before-known-values-fast-td5821461.html#a5821531): "This query and the table design itself are in dire need of sackcloth and ashes. Had the table designer had the wit to use a timestamp field rather than this unholy mashup, we'd not be having this conversation"

Comment: @CraigRinger Why to upgrade? `missing 15 patch levels` seems too abstract reason for this. 5432 port is open to public internet but I hope that there is no exploit in 9.0.3 which allows unauthorized access.

Comment: @Andrus If you want concrete reasons, *read the release notes* that show you all the fixes, in detail. There are some serious bugs in your version - including a major remote exploit. See http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-1899, http://www.postgresql.org/support/security/, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release.html . *This is why you apply patches*.

Comment: This is windows 2003 server. How to upgrade? Is is sufficient to run 9.0.18 msi installation package and point to old directory?