# Index on timestamp: Functions in index expression must be marked as IMMUTABLE

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, datetime, indexing

I want to create an index on my table for *start_time*, a timestamptz (timestamp with time zone) field in my json column called *match*.

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973030/error-functions-in-index-expression-must-be-marked-immutable-in-postgres) and [this article](http://www.depesz.com/2014/04/04/how-to-deal-with-timestamps/) I understand that you can't create an index on a timestamptz field because of different timezones and localisation. Both of these indicate that you can create an index on a timestamp (converted to text), so I tried the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_text(timestamptz) 
 RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT to_char($1 at time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US') 
  $$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Which I believe has no issues with timezones and localisation.

```
CREATE INDEX i_match_start_time ON matches (to_text(((match->>'start_time')::timestamptz)));
```

This returns the following:

> ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

I have also tried functions that return a timestamp:

```
SELECT ($1 at time zone 'UTC')
```

And functions that return unix time (tried double and casted into decimal):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM $1)
```

Each of these returns the same error.

I need to index on *start_time* because virtually all select queries to this table will be ordered by *start_time*.

Comment: `to_text()` might be immutable, but `to_text(((match->>'start_time')::timestamptz))` is not

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you explain why? And how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5):

#### Nesting `timestamptz` in JSON

> a `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone)` field in my json column

There is no such thing as a *"`timestamptz` field in a json"*. JSON only understands: *object*, *array*, *string*, *number*, *boolean*, *null*.

I'll assume this is handled properly with ISO 8601 timestamptz *strings* in the field exclusively. Else, there are more issues to solve.

Related blog:

- https://jsoneditoronline.org/indepth/parse/json-date-format/

#### Fake `IMMUTABLE`

The cast from `text` to `timestamptz` itself isn't `IMMUTABLE`. It depends on volatile settings like [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE).

In your particular case we might move the cast  into the function as a workaround:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_text(text) 
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT to_char($1::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US') 
$func$;
```

With only ISO 8601 dates, and no template patterns depending on localized settings, this is de-facto immutable. And "fake"-declaring it as such, `CREATE INDEX` won't barf.

#### Better index

However, there is now no point in casting to `text` and back. **Index the returned `timestamptz` value directly!** (Your initial assumption that this wouldn't be possible doesn't hold!)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_tstz_immutable(text) 
  RETURNS timestamptz
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN $1::timestamptz;

-- then simply:
CREATE INDEX matches_start_time_idx ON matches (to_tstz_immutable(match->>'start_time'));
```

Using an "SQL standard" function (added with Postgres 14). See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

Add `PARALLEL SAFE` in Postgres 9.6 or later. See:

- [PARALLEL label for a function with SELECT and INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70990941/parallel-label-for-a-function-with-select-and-insert/70991141#70991141)

#### Better yet

> virtually all select queries to this table will be ordered by *start_time*.

Add a generated column (added with Postgres 12) based on above function, and a plain index on that:

```sql
ALTER TABLE matches
ADD COLUMN start_time timestamptz GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tstz_immutable(match->>'start_time')) STORED

CREATE INDEX matches_start_time_idx ON matches (start_time);
```

Even simpler in day-to-day handling, and more efficient. The added 8 bytes pay when used a lot. See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-generated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

**Or** move the timestamp out of the JSON document to its own column to begin with. That would be best.