# How to create a unique index in postgresql with to_date

Tags: postgresql, indexing, to-date

We are moving from Oracle to Postgresql. In Oracle we have the following unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX USER_UI1 ON USER (LOGINID, COALESCE(DATEDELETED,TO_DATE(' 1900-01-01 00:00:00', ' YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')));
```

When I try to create a similar unique index in Postgresql I get ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

How would I create a similar unique index in Postgresql?

Edit - This is the statement I am trying in Postgresql.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX USER_UI1 ON USER (LOGINID, COALESCE(DATEDELETED,TO_DATE(' 1900-01-01 00:00:00', ' YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')));
```

Edit2 - based on klin's comment, the statement that works is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX USER_UI1 ON USER (LOGINID, COALESCE(DATEDELETED, ' 1900-01-01 00:00:00'::DATE));
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing how you are creating it in postgresql?

Comment: Okay, I've added the statement I am trying in Postgresql.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315445/index-on-timestamp-functions-in-index-expression-must-be-marked-as-immutable

Comment: Use simple cast `'1900-01-01 00:00:00'::date` instead of `to_date()`. Btw, afaik in Postgres you cannot create table `USER`.

Comment: Thank you klin! Casting to date solved the problem. And I don't really have a table called USER. I was just using it as a simple example.

Comment: BTW: you don't need an artificial sentinel. `'-infinity'::date` is an excellent fencepost.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you!