# Creating index ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Trying to implement the suggestions made to this other question:

[question related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315445/index-on-timestamp-functions-in-index-expression-must-be-marked-as-immutable)

I have written this migration to remove the current index and create the new one:

```
class ChangeIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    remove_index :part_masters, name: "part_masters_on_combo_idx" 

    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE INDEX ON part_masters (lower(unaccent(combo)) text_pattern_ops);
      CREATE INDEX ON locations (lower(unaccent(ubicacion)) text_pattern_ops);     
    SQL
   end
end
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error, I think because I'm using functions like lower or unaccent to create the index:

`PG::InvalidObjectDefinition: ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds it useful in the future, the user @laurenz-albe provided the solution for this question in the referenced question, just had to create the function unaccent as a custom pg function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_unaccent(text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS 
'SELECT unaccent($1)';
```