ERROR: syntax error at or near "$func$ postgres error
I'm trying to create the function -
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_tstz_immutable(t text)
  RETURNS timestamptz
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
$func$
BEGIN 
    RETURN date_trunc('hour', t);
END
$func$;


When I run this function I get below error -

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$func$
BEGIN
RETURN date_trunc('hour', t);
END
$func$"
LINE 4: $func$
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 128

What is the problem with this function?

Your function has several syntax issues:  

You needs as prior to dollar quoting. So perhaps as $$function$$
You cannot use the data_trunc() function with a text argument for the date parameter. I.e. must be date, timestamp, timestamptz.
An SQL function does not use/need begin ... end

Adjusting your function for the above becomes:
create or replace function to_tstz_immutable(t timestamptz)
  returns timestamptz
  language sql immutable strict parallel safe
as $func$
   select date_trunc('hour', t);
$func$;

