# PostgreSQL: Index the day part of a timestamp

Tags: postgresql, date, indexing

Consider the following table:

```
       Column       |           Type           |
--------------------+--------------------------+
 id                 | bigint                   |
 creation_time      | timestamp with time zone |
...
```

Queries like the following (let alone more complicated JOINs) takes quite a while, because they needs to calculate creation_time::DATE for each item:

```
SELECT creation_time::DATE, COUNT(*) FROM items GROUP BY 1;
```

**How do I create an index on the day part of the timestamp - `creation_time::DATE`?**

I have tried:

- `CREATE INDEX items_day_of_creation_idx ON items (creation_time)::date;`
- `CREATE INDEX items_day_of_creation_idx ON items (creation_time::date);`

But both failed with:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you create an index on an expression that expression must be put between parentheses (in addition to the parentheses that surround the column/expression list:

```
CREATE INDEX items_day_of_creation_idx ON items ( (creation_time::date) );
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get `ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`. Funny, because the day part of a date is as immutable as it gets.

Comment: @AdamMatan: ah, I overlooked the data type. The conversion of a `timestamp with time zone` to a `date` is not "immutable" (because it depends on the time zone). This would only work if you were using `timestamp without time zone`

Comment: Any way to make the conversion in the index?

Comment: @AdamMatan: this has been asked before. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5973030/330315

Comment: Thanks, will refer to that one.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, but I noticed that the index using an expression to cast a timestamp to a date used more disk space (~15%-20%) than an index on the timestamp.

I hoped for a disk space reduction in building an index on a 4 byte date over a 8 byte timestamp, but it seems that's not the case because 8 bytes seems to be the lowest common denominator for an element in the index.  So, the disk use was worse, and the query performance was about the same, so I abandoned this approach.