# How could I create an efficient index to quickly retrieve just the last day of data?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table with 118m rows of data that I can't partition just yet. I'd like to be able to quickly retrieve the last 24 hours worth of data. It is in the format:

```
created_at | page_id
timestampz     text
```

Is something like this the best way? (Getting an error about IMMUTABLE though)

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_last_day
ON my_table (created_at)
WHERE date(created_at) = date(current_timestamp) - INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Will that efficiently update if I am getting ~200k new rows per day?

Comment: When you say "the last day" do you mean "the last 24 hours" or do you mean "since midnight"? (Great name.)

Comment: hehe thanks :D - I meant the last 24 hours

Comment: That where clause is for the last day, not the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It's only necessary to have an index on `created_at::date`. The `where` qualifications are not necessary and would do strange things as `current_timestamp` changes. The [default Postgres B-tree index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-types.html) can handle equality and range queries.

Just be sure to use extra parenthesis.

```
test=> create index my_table_created_at_date on my_table((created_at::date));
CREATE INDEX

test=> analyze my_table;                                                    
ANALYZE

test=> explain select * from my_table WHERE date(created_at) = date(current_timestamp) - INTERVAL '1 day';
                                       QUERY PLAN                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using my_table_created_at_date on my_table  (cost=0.29..8.43 rows=2 width=8)
   Index Cond: (date(created_at) = (date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - '1 day'::interval))
```

Also be sure to have an index on just `created_at` to cover other non-date queries.

```
test=> create index my_table_created_at on my_table(created_at);
CREATE INDEX

test=> analyze my_table ;
ANALYZE

test=> explain select * from my_table WHERE created_at between (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 day') and current_timestamp;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using my_table_created_at on my_table  (cost=0.29..4.39 rows=5 width=8)
   Index Cond: ((created_at >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '1 day'::interval)) AND (created_at <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error: Functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE. Indexes don't seem to like dates very much

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables That's because of the `where` clause in your index. You don't need it.

Comment: I'm not, I'm only doing this: `CREATE index my_table_last_day_created_at_date ON my_table_last_day((created_at::date));`. I think it is because created_at is actually of type timestampz not timestamp.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Ah. You can't index the date of a `timestampz`. The date must be calculated from the time zone when the `select` happens so it can't be stored. It's "mutable". [You can fake it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973030/error-functions-in-index-expression-must-be-marked-immutable-in-postgres) but that hard codes the timezone at insert time defeating the point of using a timestampz. I'd suggest using `timestamp` and dealing with time zone conversion in the application. [Frameworks like Rails will do this for you](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones).