# I'm trying to create the following index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

```
CREATE INDEX request_response_partition_idx
  ON public.request_response_partition USING btree (userid,extract('Month' from time_stamp));
```

I get the error;

```
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

********** Error **********
ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
SQL state: 42P17
```

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5974139/5841306) what you want ?

Comment: What data type is the column `time_stamp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time_stamp` must be a `timestamp with time zone`.

You'll have to make the expression `IMMUTABLE` by converting it to a `timestamp without time zone` at the appropriate time zone:

```
CREATE INDEX request_response_partition_idx
ON public.request_response_partition (
   userid,
   extract('Month' FROM (time_stamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))
);
```

Of course you also have to modify the expression in your queries to match the index.

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem. But that index is not getting scanned while `explain` query.  `Explain select data from public.request_response_partition08 where userid = 12025818 
and time_stamp :: date between to_date('2019-08-10','YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '2 day' and to_date('2019-08-10','YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '2 day'` gives no index scan.

Comment: As I said in my answer, *you also have to modify the expression in your queries to match the index.* So the condition on `time_stamp` must be `extract('Month' FROM (time_stamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) BETWEEN ...`. The indexed condition has to be the same as thr expression in the query.